# Replaying html5 audio when clicking on custom forward or rewind button of AudioPlayer in backbone JS using Chrome Browser

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, avaudioplayer, html5-audio, audio-player

I am working in a application where I need to play audios related to some clicks. I got these audios through web service. So I create a backbone structure to play audios. I am using html5 audio player. I am using .wav file for audio. I am using Chrome Browser.
But 
when I clicking on custom forward or rewind button, Audio is playing from  beginning.

When clicking on custom forward or rewind button, It should move forward from current position or rewind the audio from current position. But this is not happening, it replaying audio from beginning. How can I resolve this Bug, Please someone help me to fix this.

But when I refresh the page or reopen the browser then everything working properly, means forward button move the audio to forward from current position and rewind will rewind properly.

---

### HTML template for Backbone JS

```
<audio id="myMusic" class="music" preload="true" autofocus>
      <source src="<%= data.audioFileName %>">
</audio>
<div class="audioplayer-msg1">Loading Audio File..</div>
<div class="audioplayer">
    <div class="play-component">
        <button class="rButton rewind" title="Rewind (<F3>)" disabled></button>
        <button class="pButton play" title="Play (<F2>)"></button>
        <button class="fButton forward" title="Forward (<F4>)"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="volume-component">
        <button class="tButton loud" title="Volume Decrease"></button>
        <div class="audioSlider"></div> 
        <button class="sButton sound" title="Volume Increase"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="seekBar-component">    
        <div class="timeline" title="Drag to jump to a time"></div> 
        <span class="endTime right lables" ></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS code for backbone view

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette', 'eventAggregator', 'jquery-ui', 'underscore', 'tpl!modules/audioPlayer/audioPlayer.html', 'properties/properties'], function(Backbone, Marionette, EventAggregator, jqueryui, _, audioPlayerTpl, properties) {
var duration = 0;
var musicPlayer;
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: audioPlayerTpl,
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        _.bindAll(this, 'on_keypress');
        $(document).bind('keydown', this.on_keypress);
    },
    on_keypress: function(e) {
        var audioLoadChk = localStorage.getItem("audioLoadStatus");
        if (audioLoadChk == "loaded") {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 115:
                    this.forward(e);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 113:
                    this.play(e);
                    break;
                case 114:
                    this.rewind(e);
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    },
    onDestroy: function() {
        //delete previous audio        
        if (musicPlayer) {
            musicPlayer.setAttribute('src', "");
            $(document).unbind("keydown");
            $(".audioplayer-msg1").show();
        }
    },
    onDomRefresh: function() {
        EventAggregator.on('playAudio', this.play.bind(this));
        EventAggregator.on('forwardAudio', this.forward.bind(this));
        EventAggregator.on('rewindAudio', this.rewind.bind(this));
        $(".audioplayer").hide();
        $(".audioplayer-msg").hide();
        $(".audioplayer-msg1").show();
        localStorage.setItem("audioLoadStatus", "loaded");
        musicPlayer = this.$('.music')[0];
        var timeline = this.$('.timeline'); // timeline
        var self = this;
        // timeupdate event listener
        musicPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", this.timeUpdate, false);
        musicPlayer.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
            duration = this.duration;
            self.$('.endTime').empty().append(self.formatSecondsAsTime(duration));
            var showLabel = function(event, ui) {
                var curValue = "0:00";
                var target = $('.timeline .ui-slider-handle');
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner audioplayer-tooltip">' + curValue + '</div></div>';
                $(".audioplayer-msg1").hide();
                $(".audioplayer").show();
                $(target).html(tooltip);
            };
            self.$('.timeline').slider({
                orientation: "horizontal",
                value: musicPlayer.currentTime,
                min: 0,
                max: duration,
                range: 'min',
                animate: "slow",
                step: .1,
                create: showLabel,
                slide: function(e, ui) {
                    //showLabel();
                    musicPlayer.pause(e);
                    self.$(".pButton").removeClass("pause");
                    self.$(".pButton").addClass("play");
                    musicPlayer.currentTime = ui.value;
                    self.$(".pButton").prop('title', 'Play (<F2>)');
                },
                stop: function(e, ui) {
                    musicPlayer.play();
                    self.$(".pButton").removeClass("play");
                    self.$(".pButton").addClass("pause");
                    self.$(".pButton").prop('title', 'Pause (<F2>)');
                }
            });
        }, false);
        currentSecond = {
            getCurrentSecond: function(cTime) {
                return self.formatSecondsAsTime(cTime);
            }
        }
        this.$('.audioSlider').slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            value: 0.5,
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            range: 'min',
            animate: "slow",
            step: .1,
            slide: function(e, ui) {
                /* Volume Button enble/disable*/
                if (ui.value == 0) {
                    $(".tButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else if (ui.value != 0) {
                    $(".tButton").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                if (ui.value == 1) {
                    $(".sButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else if (ui.value != 1) {
                    $(".sButton").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                musicPlayer.volume = ui.value;
            }
        });
    },
    events: {
        'click .pButton': 'play',
        'click .fButton': 'forward',
        'click .rButton': 'rewind',
        'click .sButton': 'volumeUp',
        'click .tButton': 'volumeDown'
    },
    play: function(ev) {
        // start music
        if (musicPlayer.paused) {
            console.log("paused")
            musicPlayer.play(ev);
            // remove play, add pause
            this.$(".pButton").removeClass("play");
            this.$(".pButton").addClass("pause");
            this.$(".pButton").prop('title', 'Pause (<F2>)');
        } else { // pause music
            console.log("play")
            musicPlayer.pause(ev);
            // remove pause, add play
            this.$(".pButton").removeClass("pause");
            this.$(".pButton").addClass("play");
            this.$(".pButton").prop('title', 'Play (<F2>)');
        }
    },
    forward: function(ev) {
        //musicPlayer.pause(ev);
        if (musicPlayer.currentTime == duration) {
            musicPlayer.pause();
            self.$('.pButton').removeClass("pause");
            self.$('.pButton').addClass("play");
        } else {
            var dur = musicPlayer.currentTime;
            musicPlayer.play();
            musicPlayer.currentTime = dur + 3;
            self.$('.pButton').removeClass("play");
            self.$('.pButton').addClass("pause");
        }
    },
    rewind: function(ev) {
        if (musicPlayer.currentTime > 0) {
            //musicPlayer.pause();
            musicPlayer.currentTime = musicPlayer.currentTime - 3;
            musicPlayer.play();
            self.$('.pButton').removeClass("play");
            self.$('.pButton').addClass("pause");
        }
    },
    volumeDown: function(ev) {
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") > 0) {
            musicPlayer.volume = this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") - 0.1;
            this.$(".audioSlider").slider('value', musicPlayer.volume);
        }
        /* Volume Button enble/disable*/
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") == 0) {
            $(".tButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") >= 0.1) {
            $(".sButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        /*  */
    },
    volumeUp: function(ev) {
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") < 1) {
            musicPlayer.volume = this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") + 0.1;
            this.$(".audioSlider").slider('value', musicPlayer.volume);
        }
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") == 1) {
            $(".sButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        if (this.$(".audioSlider").slider("value") < 1) {
            $(".tButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    },
    // timeUpdate 
    // Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio 
    timeUpdate: function(e) {
        if (musicPlayer.currentTime >= 3) {
            self.$(".rButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            self.$(".rButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        if (duration) {
            if (musicPlayer.currentTime <= (duration - 3)) {
                self.$(".fButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                self.$(".fButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
        //if (musicPlayer.currentTime) {
        self.$('.audioplayer-tooltip').empty().append(currentSecond.getCurrentSecond(musicPlayer.currentTime));
        self.$(".timeline").slider('value', musicPlayer.currentTime);
        //console.log(musicPlayer.currentTime + "==" + duration);
        if (musicPlayer.currentTime == duration) {
            self.$('.audioplayer-tooltip').empty();
            self.$('.pButton').removeClass("pause");
            self.$('.pButton').addClass("play");
        }
        //}
    },
    formatSecondsAsTime: function(secs) {
        var hr = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
        var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600)) / 60);
        var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) - (min * 60));
        if (hr < 10) {
            hr = hr;
        }
        if (min < 10) {
            min = min;
        }
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        return (hr > 0) ? (hr + ":" + ((min > 10) ? min : '0' + min) + ':' + sec) : (min + ':' + sec);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: If my approach is wrong or complected then please suggest me some proper approach.

Comment: *"But Audios are replaying (play audio from beginning) when I clicking on custom forward or rewind button of that Player.*" So what's the expected behavior..? BTW You can [edit] the post and add further information there. Everyone might not notice comments...

Comment: thank you for your suggetion